# whats the pro/cons to download file from web

Tags: asp.net

In the Windows 7 Enterprise edition with IIS7.

If an application's application pool is .net framework 2.0, can it use a class library written using .net framework 3.5?

Rick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An application pool in IIS is not tied to a particular version of the framework but to  a version of the CLR. It can be set to CLR 1.1, CLR 2.0 or 4.0. Because .NET 2.0 and 3.5 use both the same CLR 2.0 you can use a library compiled against .NET 3.5 without any problems.